# Product rule for 4-vectors and derivation of 4-force form

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, vectors, differentiation

In deriving the form for the 4-force in special relativity, we begin with

$$\frac{d}{d\tau}p^{\alpha}=m\frac{d}{d\tau}u^{\alpha}=f^\alpha$$

where $\tau$ is the proper time, m is rest mass.

Since $u^\alpha$ is a 4-vector, we have that $u^\alpha \frac{d}{d\tau}u_\alpha$ is frame invariant. My question is why does $u^\alpha u_\alpha = c^2 \implies u^\alpha \frac{d}{d\tau}u_\alpha = 0$? Is the usual product rule for the derivative $\frac{d}{d\tau}$ applied to the inner product of two 4-vectors valid?

Comment: To see for yourself, write out the contraction.

Comment: Try to write $\frac{d}{d\tau}(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{u})$